# Can I travel to Italy with my permesso di soggiorno?

Tags: visas, uk, italy, permesso-di-soggiorno

I have been living in the uk for 5 years now and I have settled status but I also have a permesso di soggiorno Illimitata from Italy. My husband is a Italian national but I am not. Since moving to the the uk I have been to Italy only twice. My question is that can I enter Italy without any problems?

Comment: Will you be travelling with your husband?

Comment: Are you a non-EU citizen? Have you been in the EU in the last 12 months? Does your permit mention "per familiari di cittadino dell'Unione"?